# How to optimize Angular app that's making computer fan loud?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, performance, google-chrome

So for reference, I'm using a macbook air from 2011. I keep it running pretty lean and basically only have a terminal with rails server running and using chrome.

I've been working on integrating angular into an existing rails project that's been going really well. One thing I have noticed, however is that when I go to my site, my computer fan starts to get loud, which I'm guessing is due to the angular running on the site. The site itself does not get slow at all and is still super fast and responsive but the fan getting loud does concern me.

Has anyone else run into something like this before? Are there any suggestions or resources as to how to figure this out? I know that there are a decent amount of angular optimizations I could look into but if anyone has any ideas as to where to start or what tools to use that would be great. Thanks

So I looked around and did some profiling of watchers and digest cycle time and CPU use. My watcher number is around 300 and my digest cycle time is 2-5 ms which seems ok and under the chrome CPU profiling flame chart there doesn't seem to be anything going on there either. Any ideas would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: This isn't really a programming issue, so it's probably not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'd blame Rails instead of Angular.